# Incapaz de declarar un Array en VBA (Excel 2002)

Tags: array, excel, vba

Estoy tratando de declarar un Array con la cantidad de días que tiene cada mes pero no hay manera, me da error.

```
Public Function DiasMes(Mes As Integer) As Integer
  Dias(12) As Integer

  Dias = Array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31)

End Function
```

También he probado

```
Dim Dias() as Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

No funciona.
Esta sintaxis no es correcta en VBA de Excel 2002?
Olvidemos el hecho de comprobar los años bisiestos.
De momento quiero asegurarme de que puedo declarar el array. He leído las guías diferentes sobre Arrays pero no acabo de entender algo o se me pasa alguna cosa.

Si no pongo el tamaño del array y dejo los parentesis vaciós tambíen da error.
Me da error 13 "No coinciden los tipos".

Comment: Pense que decias VB, y no he visto lo de excel mira a ver si esto te sirve :[VBA Arrays](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/)

Comment: @Capt.Teach Si lo hago de la primera forma pero cambiando As Integer por As Variant si funciona. Pero de las otra manera debería funcionar y no funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que la función array te devuelve un tipo `Variant` y por ello se dan tus errores
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function

si lo que quieres es cargar una matriz con el tipo integer te sugiero que lo carges los datos 1 a 1

```
Public Function DiasMes(Mes As Integer) As Integer
    Dim Dias(11) As Integer

    Dias(0) = 31 'Enero
    Dias(1) = 28 'Febrero
    Dias(2) = 31 'Marzo
    Dias(3) = 30 'Abril
    Dias(4) = 31 'Mayo
    Dias(5) = 30 'Junio
    Dias(6) = 31 'Julio
    Dias(7) = 31 'Agosto
    Dias(8) = 30 'Septiembre
    Dias(9) = 31 'Octubre
    Dias(10) = 30 'Noviembre
    Dias(11) = 31 'Diciembre

    DiasMes = Dias(Mes - 1)
End Function
```

o te ayudes por medio de un ciclo for

como tambien podrias usar la funcion `split`

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function?f1url

que te quedaria mas o menos asi

```
Public Function DiasMes(Mes As Integer) As String
    Dim Dias() As String

    Dias = Split("31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31", ",")

    DiasMes = Dias(Mes - 1)

End Function
```

y podrias convertir el resultado a `integer`

```
CInt(DiasMes(5))
```

Pero segun entiendo lo que quieres lograr es obtener el numero de dias que tiene x mes, podrias simplemente usar

```
Public Function DiasMes(Fecha As String) As Integer
    DiasMes = Day(DateSerial(Year(Fecha), Month(Fecha) + 1, 1) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Una pregunta. Que pasa si estamos en Diciembre y sumas 1 mes con el último metodo que has puesto? No daría error?

Comment: Para nada eso es controlado por la funcion DateSerial, efectivamente si sumas a diciembre un mes daria como resultado 13 pero la funcion DateSerial controla eso y te da como resultado enero, que si lo has notado lo que hace es darte el 1er. dia del mes siguiente para que restando 1 dia te devuelva el numero de dias

Comment: Ya veo. Muchas gracias.